# How to focus named window when I reopen it in electron.js?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a list. Click one item and then pop-up window which is named open. It's focused when it first opens, but it's out of focus the second time.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94iyT.png)

when I click a button, the following code execute. But, **winObj.focus()** **not working** in electron. It's only focus the main window. How do I fix it?

`chatList.js` (build in react)

```js
  const onClickBtn = useCallback(
    (chat) => {
      const winObj = window.open(
        `/chatting/${chat.url}`,
        chat.url,
        "",
        true
      );
      winObj.focus();
    },
    []
  );
```

`electron.js` (same as public/main.js)

```js
function createWindow() {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 400,
  height: 700,
  webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
    nativeWindowOpen: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, "/../build/preload.js"),
  },
});
const pubUrl = "https://---";
win.loadURL(pubUrl);

//when i click the button above, the event come into here.
win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler((event) => {
    return {
      action: "allow",
      overrideBrowserWindowOptions: {
        ...win.webContents.browserWindowOptions,
        parent: win,
      },
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an existing [bug](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/25578) with Electron.

`win.focus()` will not actually focus the `BrowserWindow`. You'll want to send an ipc message down to the main process, grab your `BrowserWindow` and call `win.focus()` from there.